# Whether to use “a” or "the"

Tags: word-choice, articles

It sounds natural to say “I was chatting with a friend when the phone rang.”
But it feels weird to me saying “I stopped chatting with a friend when the phone rang.”
Should it be “the friend “in the latter even though this specific friend has not been mentioned previously?

Comment: Using 'the' without any previous mention would raise the question in the listener's mind: "What friend"?

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic meaning between the two phrases you suggest are completely different.

> I was chatting with a friend when the phone rang.

This means that the phone rang *while* you were chatting with your friend, effectively interrupting your chat. "A" friend is of course non-specific, which is fine in this context because your chat with them is incidental in this statement. All the focus is on the phone ringing, what you were doing at the time was purely incidental. You could have been in the shower, watching TV, or whatever.

> I stopped chatting with a friend when the phone rang.

This would be understood to mean that you stopped chatting *because* the phone rang - the fact that it rang *made* you stop chatting. In this case, the chat is no longer incidental, as one statement is dependent on the other. They are intrinsically linked.

The most idiomatic way to express this - if that is really what you mean to say - would probably be:

> I stopped chatting with **my** friend when (*or possibly 'because'*) the phone rang.